# In return methods for Arrays, is having the index as an argument bad practice?

Tags: java, methods

So for example :

```
public static JButton[] getBtnScore(){
    return btnScore;
}

public JButton getBtnScore(int i) { /// Is this bad practice?
return btnScore[i];
}
```

I started doing this before I realised `getBtnScore()[i]` would work and now I assume it is bad practice, but I haven't had it confirmed anywhere.

Comment: There is no yes/no answer for your question. Sometimes you want that, sometimes you don't.

Comment: Agreed, with this information a yes/no cannot really be determined. In my opinion, one disadvantage of the second method is the array access is hidden. This may be a confusing to the caller when it comes the array index being out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bad practice. The problem may lie inside this method.

There are a variety of methods in Java that shows there is no problem passing the index:

- [`java.util.List#get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)
- [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

  - binarySearch
  - copyOfRange
  - fill
  - sort

---

If your question were:

> Is this a good design?

It cannot be answerable with the provided info. You would need to explain your problem in depth to help you decide that.